# treeview with golang and gtk3

Tags: go, treeview, gtk3

I use golang with gtk3

it works pretty

*treeview* :

```
tv, _ := gtk.TreeViewNew()
...
tvmodel,_ := tv.GetModel()
sel,_ := tv.GetSelection()
model,iter,ok := sel.GetSelected()
```

gives the selected node

*to manage children* :

```
nenf:=tvmodel.IterNChildren(iter)
var child gtk.TreeIter
for ind:=0; ind<nenf; ind++ {
    tvmodel.IterNthChild(&child,iter,ind)
    ...
```

it works

but *how to find the parent* ?

`iterParent` (or equivalent) seems not to exist

Comment: Looks to me like `IterParent` does exist: https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/blob/57d483abd6e13880b69a59a932167ac1c278a872/gtk/gtk.go#L4204 (upper-case, as it's part of the public API, `iterParent` won't work...)

Comment: sorry for not having clarified: I used **github.com/gotk3**
not seen IterParent (uppercase or lowercase)
I tried **github.com/mattn/go-gtk**

Comment: error github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk ; runtime.cgocall(0x5315e0, 0xc42004fdc0, 0x0)
 /mnt/ext/Exec/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:131 +0x110 fp=0xc42004fd90 sp=0xc42004fd50...
with linux manjaro

Comment: eventually I'll manage with gtk.TreePath. thank you

Comment: Oh, that error is one of the open issues, I've just changed the `gtk.Init(&os.Args)` to `gtk.Init(nil)`, that solves that problem. Obviously, it only works if you're not passing arguments when running the program, haven't looked at gotk3 though, go-gtk seems to have died, so you might be using the better package

Comment: thank you for your intervention and your help. github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk should suit me